# Xamarin gradle bindings android

Tags: gradle, xamarin.android

I had created android sdk and is on gradle.

I wanted to use it my in Xamarin project by adding its gradle dependancy.
I am following https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EgorBogatov.XamarinGradleBindings

I added XamarinGradleBindings plugin to visual studio and followed all the steps from above link.

I successful till 3rd step where we get all dependency list.
But after that I am getting following error.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

at EnvDTE80.Solution2.GetProjectTemplate(String TemplateName, String Language) 

at EgorBo.GradleBindings_VisualStudio.GradleBindings_VisualStudioPackage.CreateProjectAndAddReferenceToIt(VSProject sourceProject, Solution2 solution, String newProjectTemplate, String newProjectName, String newProjectDirectory)

at EgorBo.GradleBindings_VisualStudio.GradleBindings_VisualStudioPackage.CreateBindingProject(VSProject sourceProject, Solution2 solution, String bindingProjectName, IEnumerable`1 aarFiles, IEnumerable`1 jarFiles, IEnumerable`1 referencedJarFiles, String infoFile)

at EgorBo.GradleBindings_VisualStudio.GradleBindings_VisualStudioPackage.<GenerateAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)

at GradleBindings.BindingProjectGenerator.<Generate>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Note: I got same error when i add other gradle dependencies other than my sdk.

Can anyone have idea whats wrong with it?
Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure if this library is still maintained by the author its been almost a year since the last commit, Also its very tough to understand what could be the issue since the stacktrace is not so detailed

Comment: ok, so can you please suggest any other way to add gradle bindings to xamarin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle dependencies in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049536/gradle-dependencies-in-xamarin)