# Error inflating class android.suppot.design.widget.NavigationView'

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have this error when i start Activity with Layout in Xamarin.Android project. How to fix this? 
All android nuget packages v. 28.0.0.3

> Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.suppot.design.widget.NavigationView'

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <include
       layout="@layout/include_main"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<android.suppot.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navView"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:layout_gravity="start"
 app:headerLayout="@layout/headerlayout"
 app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**NavMenu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group>
<item
android:id="@+id/navProfile"
android:title="Профиль"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person"/>
<item android:id="@+id/navPayments"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_wallet"
android:title="Транзакции"/>
<item android:id="@+id/navHistory"
android:title="История"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_history"
/>

<item
android:id="@+id/navPromo"
android:title="Промо"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_discount"

/>
<item
android:id="@+id/navSupport"
android:title="Поддержка"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_support"
/>
<item
android:id="@+id/navAbout"
android:title="О нас"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_about"
/>
</group>

</menu>
```

**Include_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Main Layout"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
</FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**header_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView
android:id="@+id/accoutImage"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/account"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/accountTitle"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="UserName"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
/>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Splash"
   parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.Register" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
</style>
<!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette ->
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change `refractored.controls.CircleImageView` instead of `Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView` in your `header_layout` :

```
<refractored.controls.CircleImageView
android:id="@+id/accoutImage"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/account"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
/>
```

and :

```
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

instead of:

```
 <android.suppot.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: yes, i change `refractored.controls.CircleImageView` and `<android.suppot.design.widget.NavigationView>` and get this error when start activity `Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.suppot.design.widget.NavigationView'`

Comment: Are you sure you used support instead of suppot?

Comment: did you add "support:appcompat" and "support:design" in your build.gradle?

Comment: I can't find build.gradle file. Maybe visual studio don't have this file.

Comment: yes you right, see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049536/gradle-dependencies-in-xamarin

Comment: yes. The problem was that I did not inherit from the desired activity.

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled the word `support`. Just try to replace

```
   <android.suppot.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

with

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Besides, make sure the nuget:`Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView` have  been installed, otherwise the code will report the error as well.

**Note:**

I have tested that It doesn't matter if the namespace is `Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView` or `refractored.controls.CircleImageView`.They all works.

Comment: I created a new app and copied your code, it works properly.Just replaced some images. You can check it here. https://github.com/jessiezh0320/AnTestDemo

Comment: You may need to pay attention to some code,e.g.code ` app:headerLayout="@layout/headerlayout"`  should be consistent with the layout name. But I found you used `header_layout`.

Comment: Ensure your app have installed Nuget: `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design`.