# Consuming gradle dependencies in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, dolby

I am creating a Xamarin.Forms app in which I want to use [the Dolby Android SDK](https://docs.dolby.io/communications-apis/docs/initializing-android). I have gotten this to work as an Android app by adding `implementation "com.voxeet.sdk:sdk:3.4.1"` to my `build.gradle` and adding `maven { url "https://android-sdk.voxeet.com/release" }` to the `repositories` array.

From what I've gathered from the docs and searching online I will need to create an Android Binding Library to make use of this library, Unfortunately I have not found a way to get this working so far with Gradle dependencies.
There is an old [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EgorBogatov.XamarinGradleBindings) that potentially used to work but it hasn't been updated in over 4 years, I've tried using it but have had no luck with it.

I feel like my use-case should be quite common so I must be missing something obvious! What would be the best way to consume a Gradle dependency in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: you may check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049536/gradle-dependencies-in-xamarin

Comment: I have seen that post, I'm just not sure on what to do. The only viable option from there is creating an Android Binding Library but I don't believe I have a *.JAR or *.AAR file I can use to create a binding library.

Comment: Have you read the official document about binding a library in the xamarin? There is a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264285/xamarin-android-binding-to-3rd-party-sdk-with-dependencies) about binding a three part sdk in the xamarin. In additon, someone had done a [sample](https://github.com/adrianstevens/Dolby-Audio-Plug-in-for-Xamarin#xamarinandroid-dolby) which binded the Dolby Audio jar in the xamarin. You can try to download the jar file of the sdk and bind it according to it.